# Ads in Java Desktop

Tags: java, android, admob, desktop

I'm preparing to deploy a game developed using LIBGDX for both android and Desktop computers.  Is there a way to put ads in a desktop application? I'd like to generate revenue from the desktop ads too.

Comment: Could you please update us for 2021? Can we do it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to stick a browser widget in your desktop application and display adverts in there.  JEditorPane's HTML support is pretty primitive, however, so you'd have to search for an embeddable Java browser or a custom subclass of JEditorPane which supports modern HTML (I think JEditorPane support stops at HTML 3.2).  There are some freely available alternatives just a Google search away.

Off the top of my head, I can't think of any advertising networks geared towards desktop applications at all, so the browser approach is probably your only real shot at doing what you want.

Comment: That's a good idea.  It may be pretty difficult to do though, since I'll be using a LWJGL form.  Placing an ad via an embedded browser in that would be pretty ugly...

Comment: Question is, does it comply with AdMob's policies? I just commented on that topic in another question (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095890/can-admob-be-used-for-desktop-applications/12609898#12609898)

Comment: For the sake of posterity: if AdMob can't be used, [Native](http://nativex.com/monetize/desktop/) might be a solution. I have nothing to do with the company -- it just came up in a quick Google search while trying to find a copy of the AdMob TOU/license.