# Use Admob on a Java8 Application (on a Windows/Linux Computer)

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I have a small Java8 Application running primary on Windows Computers. I would like to add some Advertisment to it. So i was asking myself if i could use Admob SDK, since android is based on Java.

I know that it is possible to use some andorid libraries (os independent once) in a Java Project, but is it possible to use the specific Admob SDK to gain from their Services.

Thanks 4u help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can AdMob be used for desktop applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095890/can-admob-be-used-for-desktop-applications)

Answer (score -1):

No, this would not be possible. AdMob is a mobile ad network, and doesn't serve ads to desktop applications.